# Trying to understand recursive merge sort

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

I'm using java, I have a code given by an instructor and I am trying ti follow the code but I can't seem to make the code work.

This is code given to us :

```
public class MergeSort   {  
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Generic array allocation
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void sort(E[] A) {
      E[] temp = (E[])new Comparable[A.length];
      mergesort(A, temp, 0, A.length-1);
    }
    
    
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void mergesort(E[] A, E[] temp, int l, int r) {
        
        int mid = (l+r)/2; // Select midpoint
        if (l == r) {       
            return; // List has one element
        }
        
        mergesort(A, temp, l, mid); // Mergesort first half     
        mergesort(A, temp, mid+1, r); // Mergesort second half
        
        for (int i=l; i<=r; i++) // Copy subarray to temp
            temp[i] = A[i];
        
        // Do the merge operation back to A
        int i1 = l; int i2 = mid + 1;
        for (int curr=l; curr<=r; curr++) {         
            if ((i1< mid+1) && (i2<=r)) {
                 if (temp[i1].compareTo(temp[i2])<0) // Get smaller
                        A[curr] = temp[i1++];
                 else 
                     A[curr] = temp[i2++];              
            }
            else if ((i1==mid+1) && (i2 <= r) ){ // Left sublist exhausted
                A[curr] = temp[i2++];
            }
            else if (i2 > r) { // Right sublist exhausted
                A[curr] = temp[i1++];
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

so I added a main function inside the class Mergesort so I can follow the code using breakpoint and understand how merge sort uses recursion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Array []= {4,6,2,1,7,9,10};
        MergeSort m=new MergeSort();
        m.sort(Array);
    }
```

but it does not work: I am getting this error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method sort(E[]) in the type MergeSort is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
```

which is basically caused by `m.sort(Array)`;

This is my entire code:

```
public class MergeSort  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Array []= {4,6,2,1,7,9,10};
        MergeSort m=new MergeSort();
        m.sort(Array);
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Generic array allocation
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void sort(E[] A) {
      E[] temp = (E[])new Comparable[A.length];
      mergesort(A, temp, 0, A.length-1);
    }
    
    
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void mergesort(E[] A, E[] temp, int l, int r) {     
        int mid = (l+r)/2; // Select midpoint
        if (l == r) {       
            return; // List has one element
        }
        
        mergesort(A, temp, l, mid); // Mergesort first half
        
        mergesort(A, temp, mid+1, r); // Mergesort second half
        
        for (int i=l; i<=r; i++) // Copy subarray to temp
            temp[i] = A[i];
        
        // Do the merge operation back to A
        int i1 = l; int i2 = mid + 1;
        for (int curr=l; curr<=r; curr++) {         
            if ((i1< mid+1) && (i2<=r)) {
                 if (temp[i1].compareTo(temp[i2])<0) // Get smaller
                        A[curr] = temp[i1++];
                 else 
                     A[curr] = temp[i2++];              
            }
            else if ((i1==mid+1) && (i2 <= r) ){ // Left sublist exhausted
                A[curr] = temp[i2++];
            }
            else if (i2 > r) { // Right sublist exhausted
                A[curr] = temp[i1++];
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `int` is a primitive type you'll need to use boxed integers, i.e. `Integer Array []= {4,6,2,1,7,9,10};` (and please use Java naming conventions and call it `arrayToSort` or something else both meaningful and starting with a lower case letter.)

Comment: And `Integer[] arrayToSort = ...` is more idiomatic.